# how to fix ehcache slow flush

Tags: java, performance, ehcache, flush

Hi I am using Ehcache to save data in my application.
Each element is .

I need to stay persistance so I call the flush method on every update.

When I have 90,000 entitis in the cache the flush takes 4 seconds.

How can I fix this(the flush)?

Thanks Ido

Comment: You're using a cache to save data? What are you using a database for then, caching?

Comment: This is a cache from a centeral database.